# Приложение вылетает на Android 6 и выше

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

Здравствуйте, есть приложение(игра) под Android. Я декомпилировал его и модифицировал. Модифицированная версия вылетает на Android 6 и выше, хотя исходное приложение работает. Подскажите какие могут быть причины этого, в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Метка реверс-инжиниринг не относится к модификации. Уберите ее. Чтобы копать нужна лопата - это ваши логи. Покажите их. Я грешу на разрешения. Игра их имеет?

Comment: Или сработала какая-то защита от пересборки